# How to get the attribute of a child element based on the attribute of the parent element in css?

Tags: html, css

I want to give the color of the table based on the outer `table`.

For example , In my case there are two color blue and green. So if the color of the `table` is green so the `table` which is in that table , I want the color of that `table` Blue and this thing is happening nested.

But I just want if blue header then `td` color is light blue 
my code for `css` is as below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Custom Print_r</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 table{
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 .bl{
  border-color: #0000cc;
  text-align: left;
  background: #4444ce;
  color: white;
 }
 .gn{
  border-color: #006600;
  text-align: left;
  background: #009900;
  color: white;
 }
 tr{
  
 }
 .bl td:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: #ccddff;
  border-color: #0000cc;
  color: black;
 }
 .bl td:nth-child(even){

  background-color: white;
  border-color: #0000cc;
  color: black;
 }
 .gn td:nth-child(odd){

  background-color: #CCFFCC;
  border-color: #006600;
  color: black;
 }
 .gn td:nth-child(even){

  background-color: white;
  border-color: #006600;
  color: black;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<table border='2' class=bl ><th colspan='2' class=bl>Array</th><tr><td>a</td><td  class=bl><table border='2' class=gn ><th colspan='2' class=gn>Array</th><tr><td>aa</td><td  class=gn><table border='2' class=bl ><th colspan='2' class=bl>Array</th><tr><td>aaa</td><td  class=bl>Hi</td></tr><tr><td>bbb</td><td  class=bl>hello</td></tr><tr><td>ccc</td><td  class=bl>how</td></tr><tr><td>ddd</td><td  class=bl>are</td></tr><tr><td>eee</td><td  class=bl>you</td></tr></table></tr><tr><td>ab</td><td  class=gn><table border='2' class=gn ><th colspan='2' class=gn>Array</th><tr><td>aaa</td><td  class=gn>How</td></tr><tr><td>bbb</td><td  class=gn>may</td></tr><tr><td>ccc</td><td  class=gn>I</td></tr><tr><td>ddd</td><td  class=gn>help</td></tr><tr><td>eee</td><td  class=gn>you</td></tr></table></tr><tr><td>ac</td><td  class=gn><table border='2' class=bl ><th colspan='2' class=bl>Array</th><tr><td>aaa</td><td  class=bl>Hi</td></tr><tr><td>bbb</td><td  class=bl>hello</td></tr><tr><td>ccc</td><td  class=bl>how</td></tr><tr><td>ddd</td><td  class=bl>are</td></tr><tr><td>eee</td><td  class=bl>you</td></tr></table></tr></table></tr><tr><td>b</td><td  class=bl><table border='2' class=gn ><th colspan='2' class=gn>Array</th><tr><td>ba</td><td  class=gn><table border='2' class=bl ><th colspan='2' class=bl>Array</th><tr><td>aaa</td><td  class=bl>Hi</td></tr><tr><td>bbb</td><td  class=bl>hello</td></tr><tr><td>ccc</td><td  class=bl>how</td></tr><tr><td>ddd</td><td  class=bl>are</td></tr><tr><td>eee</td><td  class=bl>you</td></tr></table></tr><tr><td>bb</td><td  class=gn><table border='2' class=gn ><th colspan='2' class=gn>Array</th><tr><td>aaa</td><td  class=gn><table border='2' class=bl ><th colspan='2' class=bl>Array</th><tr><td>aaa</td><td  class=bl>How</td></tr><tr><td>bbb</td><td  class=bl>may</td></tr><tr><td>ccc</td><td  class=bl>I</td></tr><tr><td>ddd</td><td  class=bl>help</td></tr><tr><td>eee</td><td  class=bl>you</td></tr></table></tr><tr><td>bbb</td><td  class=gn>may</td></tr><tr><td>ccc</td><td  class=gn>I</td></tr><tr><td>ddd</td><td  class=gn>help</td></tr><tr><td>eee</td><td  class=gn>you</td></tr></table></tr></table></tr></table>
```

Comment: you have nested tables so you can use: table table table td {background-color: #CCDDFF}

Comment: OK...that's correct but all you see in above table are generated dynamically so actually you don't have idea how many are there..??

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand what you want to happen. I think the problem is that you are using the CSS descendent combinator, so at the lowest nested level the `<td>` are actually having both `.bl td:nth-child` and `.gn td:nth-child` applied. Does using the CSS child combinator do what you want? So have  `.bl > td:nth-child` and `.gn > td:nth-child` (I added the `>`)

Comment: my coding is done into php

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I am asking is that you load the page and copy the resultant `HTML` and `CSS` to a code sharing site like jsfiddle or codepen. People here will not want to setup a `PHP` environment when they can just use the output `HTML` and `CSS` to reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/dbsatisnet/print_r check it i posted as you says to me